# Angular 11 structural directive breaks when compiling via AOT

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-aot

I am attempting to migrate from Angular 8 to 11.

I have gotten everything to work except for a custom directive. The directive ***works*** when running the app using `ng serve`, but breaks when compiled with the `--aot` or `--prod` flags. The browser console log reports the following error:

```
core.js:10073 NG0303: Can't bind to 'hasPermission' since it isn't a known property of 'span'.
```

where `hasPermission` is the directive, and `span` is any element I attempt to use the directive. This used to work fine in Angular 8.

The directive itself:

```
import { Directive, OnInit, Input, ElementRef, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
  selector: '[hasPermission]',
})
export class PermissionsDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef,
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    ...
  }

  // this is the structural call we're looking for
  // the directive will respond to *hasPermission="'perm'"
  @Input('') 
  set hasPermission(value: any) {
   ...
  }
}
```

it is declared and exported using a SharedModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ...
   PermissionsDirective,
   ...
  ],
  exports: [
   ...
   PermissionsDirective,
   ...
  ]
})

export class SharedModule {}
```

and finally, it's used in many other modules/components like so:

```
some.module.ts
import { SharedModule } from 'path/shared.module';
@NgModule({
 imports: [
  SharedModule,
 ],
 declarations: [
  SomeComponent
 ]
})

somehtml.html
...
<div *hasPermission="'somepermission'">...</div>
...

some.component.ts
@Component({ templateUrl: 'somehtml.html' })...
```

I'm thinking this has something to do with the -aot flag not placing modules in the right place so that they're visible? Otherwise I don't understand why there are no issues using just `ng serve`

Minimal example shown here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rzu5jm?file=src/app/app.component.html

Browser console for the stackblitz shows the same error (NG0303)

Comment: can you reproduce on stackblitz?

Comment: sure. here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rzu5jm?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with `@Input('')`. You should not set anything inside the decorator, or if you do it needs to have the same name, that if you want to name it as an alias. Removing the empty string should fix it:

```
@Input()
set hasPermission(value: any) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

[FORKED STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fawcdm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpermissions.directive.ts)

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much. But for my own edification, why would `ng serve` without the aot optimizations work fine? It seems if the alias were incorrect, it should be incorrect regardless of how it's compiled.

Comment: Hmm... I'm getting the same error without aot too, angular 12 though?

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the rename from the decorator @Input('') -> @Input()

```js
@Input() 
set hasPermission(value: any) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: How is this different from the other answer?

Comment: @DRNR when I wrote it there was no other answer

Comment: weird, for me it shows that your answer was written 5 minutes later.

Comment: Thanks everyone! this did fix it! @Chris thanks for suggesting stackblitz.